# Bing OpenLayers shows OK in QGIS and Composer preview, but is misaligned after exporting to PDF

Tags: openlayers, export, print-composer, position

I have QGIS 2.2 running on a Mac with iOS Maverick.

I have prepared a map with layers with different CRS, including a Bing OpenLayers as base layer. The project has the 'On the fly coordinate correction' option activated, and it works OK, although sometimes things go out of position, but nothing a refresh from a pan doesn't solve.

Paraphrasing part of question #51986:
"Sometimes when changing the scale (scrolling in and out) the [Bing] layer updates (...) wrong in (...) position compared to the polygon layer. But as soon as I "pan" the map everything reconstructs right. Now the problem I have concerns the print composer."

"The result of any kind of export - pdf, or image or svg - of my map (vector layer + [Bing] layer in the background) differs from what is shown in the preview of the print composer: the vector layer and the Google layer positions are mismatching (...)"

Could this be related to On the fly correction?

Any ideas?

[image: Screen capture from QGIS 2.2, with layers correctly aligned]
[image: Screen capture from PDF created with QGIS Composer, showing the misaligned Bing layer]